# How to read in a csv with multiple columns with SuperCSV

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, supercsv

I have a CSV file containing 2 columns (1 containing a list of words, another with the frequency they are used in a text document). I was curious the best way to read that in an ArrayList of type object using SuperCSV. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you've read the documentation and examples on the Super CSV [website](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html)?

If you use `CsvListReader` with cell processors (I'd recommend something like `new CellProcessor[]{new NotNull(), new NotNull(new ParseInt())}` then you'll get a List of Objects - but you will have to cast to the appropriate type when getting the values out of the List. If you don't use cell processors you'll get a List of Strings and have to convert the count to an Integer- it's up to you but I prefer to let Super CSV to all the conversions.

You can always use `CsvBeanReader` to avoid any casting - you'll just have to create a bean with 2 fields: word (String) and count (Integer) and their getters/setters.

It's totally up to you - there really is no 'best way', but using a CSV library is a good practice. In terms of storing the result of the word frequencies, I'd recommend a `Map<String,Integer>` (word -> count).

Comment: I have looked at the site's examples and have the cell processor function but no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

First setup a Processor:

```
    private static CellProcessor[] getProcessors() {

        final CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[] {
                new NotNull(new ParseInt()), 
                new NotNull(), 
                new NotNull(), 
                new Optional(new ParseLong())

        };
        return processors;
    }
```

Next up:
Build a reader ( there are 3 types) so for our examples we can use this:

```
listReader = new CsvListReader(
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(CSVFILE, CHARSET),CsvPreference.TAB_PREFERENCE);
listReader.getHeader(false);
while ((listReader.read(processors)) != null) {}
```

And you are done, good luck.